# rails routing question - restful url pointing to different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 app with a url like this: `/books/1/pages/2`

I want this to actually point to the `Books` controller but with a `page_id` param, rather than the `Pages` controller with the `book_id` param. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

In routes.rb: `match '/books/:id/pages/:page_id' => 'books#your_action'`